How to achieve Voice Conversion Using Voice Samples of a Specific Person using any voice as input?
I'm working on a project involving voice conversion, aiming to transform a voice to sound like a specific person speaking Darija (a Moroccan Arabic dialect). I have collected a set of voice samples from the target person and prepared them in a folder containing WAV audio files. I want to have a model that converts any voice to this specific voice.Are there any models that may achieve this task?

The body of the question is now a lot shorter, but the question is still way to broad to answer succinctly.
